# Post multilevel dict from python application to python webservice

Tags: python, django

I am working on an automation script (that I am using to automate the process of conversion of some videos). In this script after video conversion, I am calling my web service to update the clip status in database and sending the web service a list of clips in POST request. But the problem is this request is failing and causing 500 internal server error on server side.

Here is the code I am using to call the web service with sample data I am trying with:

```
    post_body = {
        'clips': [
            {
                'clip_id': 17555,
                'db_url': '/720p/14555.mp4'
            }
        ]
    }
    params = urlencode(post_body)
    url = str(self.update_url)
    req = urllib2.Request(url, params)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    res = response.read()
    print res
```

And here is the code of my web service:

```
def update_conversion_clips(request):
    print "Web service is called"
    try:
        clips = request.POST.get('clips', None)
        print clips
        return HttpResponse(True)
    except:
        return HttpResponse(False)
```

Even first print statement is not executing.

Here is the error stack trace on application side:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "conversion_script.py", line 48, in <module>
  conversion_script.run()
File "conversion_script.py", line 44, in run
  self.clips.update_clips_info(None)
File "/home/abc/video_experiments/conversion/clips_manager.py", line 59, in update_clips_info
  response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
  return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
  response = meth(req, response)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
  'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 444, in error
  return self._call_chain(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
  raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
```

and this is error on server side:

```
[20/Feb/2014 04:13:15] "POST /update_conversion_clips HTTP/1.1" 500 68733
```

According to my research this is happening due to multilevel dict that I am sending in POST. But I could not find any solution to resolve it.

**New code now sending data as json (still does not work):**

```
values = dict()
values['clips'] = [
    {
        'clip_id': 17555,
        'db_url': '/720p/14555.mp4'
    }
]
req = urllib2.Request(self.update_url)
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(values))
res = response.read()
print res
```

and on server side:

```
try:
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    clips = data['clips']
except:
    print "Exception occured!"
HttpResponse(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

urlencode isn't really a good format for this data. A much better one would be JSON.

```
req = urllib2.Request(self.update_url)
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')

response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(data))
print response.read()
```

(you could make this part a lot simpler by using the third-party [requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library).

And in the server:

```
clips = json.loads(request.body)
```

Comment: thanx for your reply! I tried with new code as you suggested but still  it gives me same error i.e. 500 internal server error!!! I have also added new code in edit.

Comment: Please, please, please don't catch all exceptions and just print "exception occurred". That's totally counter-productive. Let Python show you the error, then we will know what's actually going wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: I tried without try catch but still it does not show any exception on server side! Just this error is shown in putty session "[24/Feb/2014 06:05:06] "POST /content/update_conversion_clips HTTP/1.1" 500 68889
" I think there is no error in my view because not even first code statement of the view is executed.

Comment: And same error is shown on my application side that I have mentioned in my question!